# Azure security status: security KB Deployment status and Detailed status

Tags: windows-10, security

I tried to find the definitions and ended up here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/update-compliance-security-update-status
but I'm unable to find a list of terminology.

Deployment: Unknown, In Progress, Progress Stalled, Failed, Update Completed, Completed, Deferred and Canceled.

Detailed: Download started, Download succeeded, Download hand off, Install hand off, Reboot pending, Service Stack Downloaded, Update offered, Update detected.

Does anyone know, please?

Comment: Update completed and completed ? Where did you see this ? That is a very odd way of defining update status. We call a machine either compliant or non- compliant, patched, un-patched orreboot pending. We call an update installed, not installed or failed

Comment: @pun it comes from the field 'deployment status' from azure security update status

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/update-compliance-perspectives

for most of the states.